# CORS in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I can't configure CORS in Laravel because there is no file cors.php

I'm new to Laravel. And I wanted to configure CORS so that the front on the react could send API requests to Laravel. It was written on the Internet that you need to configure this in a file config\cors.php . But I don 't have this file at all . I tried to manually add it, but nothing came of it and nothing works once I write here. Could you explain in detail and step by step how to set up CORS and make it work